# Cant change css file in meteor admin-lte

Tags: javascript, meteor, adminlte

I am using [meteor admin-lte](https://github.com/meteor-factory/meteor-admin-lte) for frontend. I want to edit the `AdminLTE.min.css` file to change `.wrapper` and `.content-wrapper` in it. The reason is that I am getting only half the screen height rendered and when `position` in `.wrapper` in changed from relative to inherit, the height of sidebar becomes 100%.

When I change the `AdminLTE.min.css`, changes happen as expected in the app. But if I close the app and start again, the CSS file doesn't have those changes. How do I make changes here? I couldn't find any `.less` or other precompiled file in the `meteor admin-lte` theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own CSS file. Then your have imported the CSS file on client side.

You need to write following CSS in that file.

```
.wrapper {
    position: initial; //You can use !important in case it doesn't overwrite the CSS. 
}
```

> Note: Pleae make sure your file load after the admin lte css files.